# Angular 2.0 Release: Pipes and Directives are not properties of @Component anymore

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-pipe

I just upgraded my app which I built on RC5 to the final release, and I'm confused of the way I should be declaring Directives and Pipes now. I'm getting this error:

> ERROR in [default] C:\xampp\htdocs\meriem-car\public\src\app\components\administration.component.ts:12:4
>   Argument of type '{ moduleId: string; selector: string; directives: typeof LoginComponent[]; templateUrl: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Component'.
>     Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'directives' does not exist in type 'Component'.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Since RC6, all Directives and Pipes should be moved to module's `declarations`.

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [...],
    declarations: [
        //you insert your Components, Directives and Pipes here
    ],
    bootstrap: [...],
    providers: [...]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: @ESturzenegger Have you removed `directives` from your component?

Comment: sry for deleting my question: "Even after adding it to declarations, it shows me the same error" @StefanSvrkota yes i did. The funny thing is: the pipe works but the error shows in my cli.

Comment: @ESturzenegger Well I don't know really, try restarting/refreshing your project. It's really weird.

Comment: @StefanSvrkota according to the docs is the pipe property not existent: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Component-decorator.html